# WinPE 5 - How can I change the USB/CDROM drive letter?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, winpe

If i boot up my custom WinPE 5 x64 image from an USB stick the following drive letters are assigned:

C: ==> USB Stick

X: ==> RAM Disk

This seems to be a problem for our SCCM 2012 staging process as it is expecting drive letter C: to be available. So I tried to change the driver letter using TSConfig.ini and some PowerShell WMI calls. Unfortunately this doesn't work and results in task sequence errors as SCCM is not aware of that change.

So to cut it short: How can I change the drive letter of a WinPE image running from USB stick or CDROM drive? NB: I do not want to change the RAM disk drive letter.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible in startnet.cmd to add a scripted diskpart section. Use something like:

`diskpart
select disk 0
select partition 1
assign letter=S
exit`

keep in mind, I'm not sure how your disk and partition numbers will appear. You will need to find that out to put in your script. And "S" ofcourse can be any letter you choose

EDIT: If not within startnet.cmd, then possibly a separate script and just add it as a [launchapp] entry in winpeshl.ini